# Insert multidimensional json/array into multidimensional json/array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to insert some data into sub in json data with foreach

example :

- each house have one or more rooms
- rooms data in sub house

this the code:

```
<?php

$houses = Houses::find()->all();
foreach($houses AS $house){
    $a[] = [
        'house_name' => $house->name,
         'color_wall' => $house->color_wall,
    ];

    $rooms = Rooms::find()->where(['house_id' => $house->id])->all();
    foreach($rooms AS $room){
        $b[] = [
            'room_name' => $room->name,
            'color_wall' => $room->color_wall,
        ];
    }
    array_push($a,$b);
}
```

I want the array to look like this:

```
[
    {
        'house_name' : 'house 1',
        'color_wall' : 'white',
        'room' : [
            {
                'room_name' : 'guest room',
                'color_wall' : 'blue',  
            },
            {
                'room_name' : 'primary room',
                'color_wall' : 'green', 
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But I can't input rooms into the sub-arrays.

```
[
    {
        'house_name' : 'house 1',
        'color_wall' : 'white',
    }
    {
        'room_name' : 'guest room',
        'color_wall' : 'blue',  
    },
    {
        'room_name' : 'primary room',
        'color_wall' : 'green', 
    }
]
```

Comment: If your Eloquent relationships are set up you won't need to do this manually.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't"? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the room data and save in a room arr and then add this room arr in house arr.

Please use this code.

```
 <?php

        $houses = Houses::find()->all();
        foreach($houses AS $house){

            $house_name = $house->name;
            $color_wall = $house->color_wall;

            $rooms = Rooms::find()->where(['house_id' => $house->id])->all();
            $room_data = [];
            foreach($rooms AS $room){
                $room_data[] = [
                    'room_name' => $room->name,
                    'color_wall' => $room->color_wall,
                ];
            }

            $a[] = [
                'house_name' => $house_name,
                'color_wall' => $color_wall,
                'room' => $room_data,
            ];
        }

        print_r($a)
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add house id to your house dataset.

Loop through your houses array and check if the house key equals the room dataset.
If so, add it to the houses array under 'rooms'.

## Example:

```
foreach(Houses::find()->all() as $house) {
    
    $house['rooms'] = [];

    $house_rooms = Rooms::find()->where(['house_id' => $house->id])->all();
    foreach($house_rooms as $room) {
        $house['rooms'][] = $room;
    }

}

var_dump($houses);
```

TLDR; Add room id to your $houses array, loop through each house and collect the room that belongs to the house individually.